# Container Python não responde requisições nem loga no terminal

Tags: python, docker, http-request, deploy

Eu estou engatado num problema desde ontem e consiste no seguinte:
Eu tenho uma API em Flask que roda num container Docker e eu faço a build normalmente na minha máquina e consigo acessar e fazer requisições, tudo ok. O problema é que quando subo pro servidor da empresa o Container roda mas não responde as requisições, causando erro de timeout. No servidor ele nem sequer loga no console, enquanto localmente roda normalmente. Nós temos outras APIs que usam o mesmo modelo e funcionam.
Se alguém tiver alguma idéia ou já passou por isso, estarei ouvindo.

Vou deixar alguns códigos que acredito ser úteis mas se for necessário algo mais é só comentar que eu adiciono.

1. Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

LABEL company="company"
LABEL aplicacion="api-voucher"
LABEL version="2.1.3"
LABEL sector="Sector"
LABEL leader="Leader"
LABEL author="Autor"
LABEL email="email@company"

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

ENV LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
ENV TZ=America/Maceio

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 6062

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

2. app.py:

```py
import sys

from config import settings
from src.controllers.campanha_controller import campanha_namespace
from src.controllers.voucher_controller import voucher_namespace
from src.server.instance import server

server.api.add_namespace(voucher_namespace, "voucher")
server.api.add_namespace(campanha_namespace, "campanha")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Inicializando {settings.app_title} v{settings.version}")
    print(f"Acesse a documentacao em http://{server.host}:{server.port}/docs")

    try:
        server.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Finalizando servidor")
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Já viu se tem firewall ou outra aplicação usando a mesma porta.

Comment: Já sim, e aparentemente não há nada sendo executado na mesma porta. Vou tentar uma configuração de proxy no Flask pra ver se funciona

Comment: Qual comando está usando para "subir" o container? Os códigos disponibilizados parecem ok. O que eu gostaria de ver é o comando `docker run .....` os parâmetros e argumentos que está utilizando para executar o docker run